# Match a range of file names with variable end, in a Bash script

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a number of files named file1, file2, file3, and so on. I'm trying to find a way to match the first N files, in a Bash script, where N is a variable. Here are the options I've considered so far:

- Brace expansion, i.e. `file{1..3}`, doesn't allow variable end. In other words, `file{1..$N}` doesn't work.
- A range expression can be used to match numeric characters. It allows variable end, i.e. `file[1-$N]`, but this works only until N > 9.
- `$(seq 1 $N)` can be used to create a sequence of numbers, but it doesn't help since the problem is to match a sequence of numbers in a file name. Were the files name simply 1, 2, 3, and so on, this would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution. I'm not advocating it, but then again there can be legitimate uses for `eval` ;) ...also I think not being able to use a variable in a range is an annoying/less intuitive shortcoming.

```
N=5
eval echo {1..$N}
```

So you could do

```
eval ls file{1..$N}
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks like a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using extended globs. They need to be enabled with `shopt -s extglob` command. `@(...)` can be used to match any of a set of patterns separated by | character, e.g. `file@(1|2|3)`. Now I just need to generate the number sequence with | as the separator character instead of a newline:

```
shopt -s extglob
range=$(seq 1 $N)
ls file@(${range//$'\n'/|})
```

Comment: If your version supports it, `seq -s '|' 1 $N` will provide a pipe-separated string of numbers, letting you use simply `file@($range)` as the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply do,

```
for file01.txt, file02.txt, file345.txt, file678.txt...

cat file*.txt > file_all.txt
```

or am I missing the point?

Comment: It looks like the asker wants to be able to stop the matching at some arbitrary number, `file*.txt` would match every file.